# HTML JS Open new window with console in google chrome

Tags: javascript, html, client-side, google-chrome-console

This is client-side HTML. I'm just using HTML for automation.

My initial goal was to open a new window https://live.ipms247.com/login/ and then paste the values in the three login fields. All three fields have ID tags. And I can write to them from the console. For example.

```
document.getElementById("username").value="sample"; 
document.getElementById("hotelcode").value="12345"; 
document.getElementById("password").value="Password";
```

I wrote a code to copy text from parent window to child window at the click of a button.
My code is on a local file.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
    popupWin = window.open('https://live.ipms247.com/login/','popupWin','');
}
function transferText()
{
    popupText = popupWin.document.getElementById("username");
    parentText = document.getElementById("parentTextBox");
    popupText.value = parentText.value
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="parentTextBox" onkeyup="transferText();" value="Hello World">
<input type="button" onclick="init();" value="popup window">
<input type="button" onclick="transferText();" value="Transfer Text">
</body>
</html>
```

However, this does not work, apparently because my code is on a local file and the website is on another domain.

So my only solution to this problem, so far, is to launch the site with onlick and then focus to it. Press Ctrl+Shift+J to open the console and then paste the commands (I have code which copies them to clipboard) and hit enter.

Is there any possibility to launch the new window with the console open and focus on the console?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only do this with Electron, as accessing, loading and handling two or more windows would be a heavy security flaw. Note that this is not only a local error, happens on any environement. I guess you could disable your browser security but that's pretty much it, and it would apply only for you

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this because JavaScript restricts you to the user.

> If you want to reach your goal, you can use the  [frames API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)